# Does Python requests timeout kwargs effect other request timeouts in the same process?

Tags: python, timeout, python-requests

How does setting a timeout using Python's requests library work internally?

Is setting a timeout for a request actually setting a global timeout on the socket used by all other requests in the process?

In other words by using the timeout kwarg for a given request, am I affecting the timeouts for subsequent requests in the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a timeout is set *per created socket*:

```
sock = socket.create_connection(
    address=(self.host, self.port),
    timeout=self.timeout,
)
```

This is all handled by `urllib3`, the lower-level library used by `requests`; see their [API documentation](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pools.html#api):

> **timeout** – Socket timeout in seconds for each individual connection. This can be a float or integer, which sets the timeout for the HTTP request, or an instance of `urllib3.util.Timeout` which gives you more fine-grained control over request timeouts. After the constructor has been parsed, this is always a *urllib3.util.Timeout* object.

`requests` makes use of the [`util.Timeout` class](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#timeout) for this to ensure both connecting and reading are subject to the timeout.